# Import Tensorflow: Failed to load the native Tensorflow runtime. I don't know what to do I tried so many ways and it still doesn't work

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm currently trying to install tensorflow for a project with someone... But I keep getting this stupid error when I'm importing the module. The thing is my computer does not have a NVIDIA graphic card (I have an INTEL one...), so I can't install GPU version, which in my case is no big deal because I'm not looking for performance. So I tried to reinstall it with so many ways like installing the tensorflow-cpu version, installing an older version, reinstalling python 3.7... I have been searching on the internet for more than 3 days and every single solution given did not work for me! I watche 10 tutorials on Youtube and nothing worked. So here is my computer settings (ask if you need something else):

- Intel core i3
- Intel graphic card
- Windows 10 Family x64
- I installed python 3.8 and Python 3.7(for tensorflow)
- I installed VC_redist.x64
- I upgraded pip (even though I already had the latest version)
- I added Python 3.8 to PATH (but not Python 3.7 because I did not know if it would create a conflict)

When I install it I get this:

```
> WARNING: The script tensorboard.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\olivi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

> WARNING: The scripts saved_model_cli.exe, tensorboard.exe, tf_upgrade_v2.exe, tflite_convert.exe, toco.exe and toco_from_protos.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\olivi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

and when I try to import it I get:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\olivi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\olivi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\olivi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\olivi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\olivi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Une routine d’initialisation d’une bibliothèque de liens dynamiques (DLL) a échoué.

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\olivi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\olivi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\olivi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\olivi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\olivi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\olivi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\olivi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\olivi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\olivi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\olivi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\olivi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\olivi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Une routine d’initialisation d’une bibliothèque de liens dynamiques (DLL) a échoué.


> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

> See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I don't know what to do! If someone could help me because I feel a bit lost...
Also, I'm French so there might be some mistakes in this post, don't hesitate to tell me where!
Thanks!

Edit: I may I found something... My CPU is a Intel Core i3 M380, and I can't find if it support AVX which is apparently needed for tensorflow... Does someone know?

Comment: You must add the directory 'C:\Users\olivi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts' to your system PATH. Here is a good explanation how to do it: https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/

Comment: Ok thanks it is done but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Is the warning still the same?

Comment: As I can see on this website https://technical.city/en/cpu/Core-i3-6006U-vs-Core-i3-380M your CPU doesn't support AVX.

Just as an idea: Why don't you use smth like google Colab or Jupytier Notebook in your browser? It fits perfect for a project with someone and you don't have to deal with technical issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Well that's what we end up doing! We are working on ParperSpace which is really cool and powerfull!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider this question answered because my CPU does not support AVX. I don't know if the errors I got were du to that but as I won't be able to work with tensorflow on my computer anyway...